# Server 2012 + Exchange 2013 - Mail not routing

Tags: email-server, windows-server-2012, exchange-2013, outlook-2013, exchange

Very strange behaviour working fine one day and not another. No patches installed from when it worked to when it didn't.

SMTP receive connectors are also refusing connections now.

No issues that I can tell with DNS or AD and there is nothing glaringly obvious in the event  logs. The only thing I have found is that when mail is "Sent" from the outlook client or OWA it gets put in to drafts and not outbox and nothing in the submission queues.

We can't even mail internally which is strange!

Any ideas anyone?

any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your Windows and Exchange log files. I'm sure there are reams of relevant logs that you can find and post here.

Comment: Back Pressure? - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201658(v=exchg.150).aspx#Pressure

Comment: Not back pressure .. it was the first thing I thought of. (to clarify - back pressure i.e. caused by low disk space?)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common problem that seems to be related (in most cases, anyway) to problems with DNS configuration. Make sure that Exchange is using the DNS servers you want it to, which may or may not be the same as the ones you have bound to the NIC in that server. http://thoughtsofanidlemind.com/2013/03/25/exchange-2013-dns-stuck-messages/ has a pretty good explanation of why this issue occurs and how to fix it.

Comment: I had configurd external / internal DNS on the transport. Don't think it was a DNS issue.